# Can I not use generic?

Tags: c#, generics

```
void LoadParameters<TValue>(Type i1, TValue i2)
        where TValue : i3;
{    
Tvalue A;
```

Saw this code and I modified slightly as it proprietary

I was thinking whether it the same as

```
void LoadParameters(Type i1, TValue i2)
{
i3 A;
```

Since the developer already know that A is of type i3, where not just specify in the code?

Comment: What are you trying to do actually? I guess you probably meant `LoadParameters(Type i1, i3 i2)`.

Comment: The first one also declares a confusingly named variables type in its parameters

Comment: yes, i3 is an interface. My mistake to change all name to i1, i2, i3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong:

> Since the developer already know that `A` is of type `i3`, where not just specify in the code?

`TValue` can either be `i3` **or any derivate** of it! If `i3` is an interface, you can either call the method like this:

```
LoadParameters<i3>(...);
```

or with any type that implements `i3`:

```
class Foo : i3 { }
interface IBar { }
class FooBar : Foo, IBar { }

LoadParameters<Foo>(...);     // Okay
LoadParameters<IBar>(...);    // fails, because IBar does not inherit from i3!
LoadParameters<FooBar>(...);  // Okay, because FooBar inherits from Foo that implements i3!
```

If you call `LoadParameters` wrong (like in the second example), the *compiler* complains about it. Without using the constraint, you will run into runtime exceptions, that are way harder to debug. So constraints help to make code more readable by supporting the developer calling a method the right way, instead of running into exceptions and let him fix his code.

Comment: `LoadParameters<IBar>(...);` would also fail for the non-generic version which uses `i3` directly.

Comment: Yes, usually. But there are exceptions: for example if there's any conversion operation that makes it possible to implicitly convert `IBar` into `i3`.

Comment: Actually - this answer doesn't help to explain at all, why it makes a difference in the posted situation. Since I3 would declare the parameter you cannot call this method wrong....

Comment: See my answer - it only makes a different, if you actually use the provided generic class information inside the Method (i.e. by calling a generic constructor) If you don't do this, the generic makes absolutely no difference!!!

Answer (score 1):

Is not the some as void `LoadParameters<TValue>` will be inferred at compile time so you  can take advantage of generics type as

- Compile Time Checking
- Dynamic over static means that  you can use any type you want with  your generic algorithm

think  of the first  version  as you can load any type of parameters with the same generic code without creating more version each time you need to get a new type

Answer (score 0):

The restriction of type arguments in C# is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). In your case, `TValue` can take any type which derives from `i3` in the first case where in the second case `A` will be exactly of type `i3`.

Comment: when you link to external sites, please also summarize shortly the relevant information

Comment: No - its not.... If I3 is an interface a Parameter of Type I3 means "Any class which can be cast to I3)

Comment: @Falco You are right, it depends on the remaining part of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From a callers perspective you are right - its actually quite exactly the same to write:

```
1. LoadParameters<TValue>( Type v1, TValue v2 ) where TValue : Interface3;
  or
2. LoadParameters( Type v1, Interface3 v2 );
```

It doesn't make a difference - when calling method2 the compiler will check that the provided parameter is castable to Interface3 (exactly the same as with an generic type argument) and if you want the syntactic sugar of being sure your Object is not only Interface3 but from a certain subclass you can equally call:

```
1. LoadParameters<Foo>( v1, v2 );
2. LoadParameters( v1, (Foo)ve ); // Explicit Casting provides static type-checking
```

soooo.... where is the difference? Why do we even need generics?

The answer lies not in the signature but inside the Method... Imagine you want to construct a new Object inside the Method, or create a generic List. - With the Generic **TValue** you can easily call TValue->newInstance() or create a List. Imagine the Generic type as a third parameter where you get an additional Class-Information, which doesn't need to be the runtime class of v2, but v2 has to be castable to that class...